# How would Newtonian gravity work in a 1-dimensional universe?

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law, spacetime-dimensions

I have come across the idea of gravity in different dimensional space. From the standard formula for gravity $F=\frac{GMm}{r^2}$ I have found that the $1/r^2$ term is a result of a three dimensional space which a gravitational field permeates. In general, for an $n$ dimensional space the force of gravity is $F\propto \frac{1}{r^{n-1}}$.

In 1 dimensional space this leads to an odd conclusion of $F\propto 1$, the force doesn't decrease as the distance between objects increases.

This is quite counter-intuitive. Is there a false assumption which I am making?

If this conclusion is true then is there a simple explanation for why the gravitational field doesn't weaken over distance? We are used to thinking of gravity as just a force but really it is a field, perhaps if this was explained in terms of fields it would make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On way to think about it is the gravitational flux: In 3D, when you are further away from an object, you receive a lesser portion of overall flux, whereas in 1D, the flux does not decrease with the distance. This also explains why an infinite plane in 3D also yields a constant gravitational field, as the flux in this case also does not change with distance.

Answer (score 3):

A gravitational force that is distance independent and constant is nothing new. This is possible even in three dimensions. If we imagine an infinite plane in $\mathbb R^3$,
[image]

then solving Poisson's equation for gravity, $\nabla^2\phi=2\pi G \rho \delta(z)$ and computing the force $F = -\nabla \phi$ will show that the gravitational field is a constant and always towards the plane as shown.

Comment: What happens if we stack many planes on top of each other to make a 3D object which has a finite length in one direction? Does that 3D object have a constant force? This seems to be a 3D version of the 1D case of "stacking" many 0D points to form a line object with constant gravitational force.

Comment: @Hugh Remember that the gravitational force being constant in one dimensions is for a point mass. An arbitrary distribution of mass $\rho(x)$ in $\mathbb R$ will *not* give rise to a constant field.

Comment: I believe the OP meant that for a single point object, the gravitational field it produces doesn't die off with distance in 1-D.  Of course you can get a constant gravitational field in any dimension if you have constant matter density.

Comment: @Travis There is no "why" to it other than looking at the derivation of $\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$. And constant matter density does not imply a constant field. What are you on about? The integral $\int_V \frac{\rho}{|x-x'|}d^3x'$ is in general not constant for constant $\rho$.

Comment: @JamalS If we use $\frac{1}{r^{d-1}}$ as the gravitational force then in 1 dimension for an object which has a length from point $a$ to point $b$ then the integral is $\int_a^b \frac{\rho(r)}{r^{1-1}} dr$ which is not a function of how far |ab| is from the point mass.

Comment: @Hugh It's actually $\int \rho(r) r \, \mathrm dr$ in one dimension, and point is it can be $r$ dependent. (Remember, $-\nabla \phi \sim 1$ so $\phi \sim r$.)

Comment: Given your other answer I'm not sure that we are talking about the same $r$

Answer (score 2):

The fact $F \propto r^{1-d}$ follows from Gauss' law for gravity. In more detail, one has that,

$$\iint_S g \cdot dS \sim M$$

where $M$ is the mass enclosed by the closed surface $S$. If we take a point mass, enclosed by a sphere, then because of the symmetry of the problem, we can take $g$ to only depend radially. Then,

$$g \mathrm{Vol}(S^{d-1}) \sim M$$

and since $\mathrm{Vol}(S^{d-1}) = 2\pi^{d/2} r^{d-1}/\Gamma(d/2)$, one has,

$$g \sim \frac{M}{r^{d-1}}.$$

Comment: You are taking $r$ to be the radius of a hypersphere but I was using it to refer to the distance between two points attracting each other by gravity.

Comment: @Hugh It is... Have you not done classical mechanics to see this done in the context of electromagnetism to derive the electricl field? $r$ here is the distance away from the point mass, and at any instant in time can be seen as the radius of a sphere.

Comment: Thanks Jamal, that rings a bell from a physics class 5 years ago. It makes sense now